# How to control caption position within subfigure?

Tags: graphics, align, captions, vspace, figure-placement

Consider the following code

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
           \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
           \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
   \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \par\medskip
   \caption{Example main caption}
\end{figure}
```

which gives

[image]

Is it possible to raise the `\caption{}` of a single subfigure? For example, get something like

[image]

I have tried something like `\vspace{-2mm}\caption{}\vspace{2mm}`, but it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\captionseup` inside `subfigure` environment will only affect that sub-caption

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[sub]{position=bottom}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
    \captionsetup{skip=1pt}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{A}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{B}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Example main caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any reason you changed `[b]` to `[t]`?

Comment: If you keep `[b]`, you essentially tell latex to align both groups w.r.t bottom parts per group, here captions. Because of a reduced distance between an image and a caption on the left, the whole image would be moved downwards. `[t]` on the other hand, tell latex to align both groups w.r.t. to top parts, here images.